# Adding Element to Class Array with function. "Paint" in Processing 3

Tags: java, arrays, class, arraylist, processing

I'm trying to create a "Paint" application with Processing 3, and I want to add buttons to change the color (later on for brushes, size, etc).

I'm stuck because I'm keep getting a `NullPointerException` for adding the button to my array.

(I know i could just ask for the mouseX and Y after creating every button without the array but it seems a bit unprofessional to me and would get very messy by time).

ERROR: Line 24 -> "allButtons[counter].name = Name;"

*Sidenote: I'm pretty new to Processing / Java xd

This is my code:

```
class button
{
  public String name; 
  public int x;
  public int y;
  public color curColor;
};

color currentColor = color(0, 0, 0);
String currentBrush = "Brush";
int currentBrushSize = 3;
button[] allButtons = new button[100];
int buttonSize = 20;
int counter = 1;

void setup() {
  size(800, 600);
  background(255);
  surface.setResizable(true);
  surface.setTitle("Not Skribble");
}

    void button(String Name, int X, int Y, color CurColor) {
      allButtons[counter].name = Name;
      allButtons[counter].x = X;
      allButtons[counter].y = Y;
      allButtons[counter].curColor = CurColor;
      counter += 1;
      fill(CurColor);
      rect(X, Y, buttonSize, buttonSize);
      if (overButton(X, Y, X + buttonSize, Y + buttonSize)) {
        fill(0, 0, 0, 80);
        rect(X, Y, buttonSize, buttonSize);
      }
    }

boolean overButton(int minX, int minY, int maxX, int maxY) {
  if (mouseX >= minX && mouseX <= maxX) {
    if (mouseY >= minY && mouseY <= maxY) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

boolean buttonPressed(String name) {
  for (int i = 0; i < allButtons.length; i++) {
    if (name == allButtons[i].name) {
      if (mouseX >= allButtons[i].x && mouseX <= allButtons[i].x + buttonSize) {
        if (mouseY >= allButtons[i].y && mouseY <= allButtons[i].y + buttonSize)         {
          if (mousePressed) {
            return true;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}

void setColor(color settingColor) {
  currentColor = settingColor;
}

void setBrush(String settingBrush) {
  currentBrush = settingBrush;
}

void setBrushSize(int settingBrushSize) {
  currentBrushSize = settingBrushSize;
}

void colorButtons() {
  button("Orange", 10, 10, color(255, 100, 0));
  if (buttonPressed("Orange")) setColor(color(255, 100, 0));

  button("Blue", 50, 10, color(255, 100, 0));
  if (buttonPressed("Blue")) setColor(color(0, 0, 255));
}
void brushButtons(){

}
void settingButtons(){

}

void draw() {
  noStroke();
  fill(100);
  rect(0, 0, width, 70);

  colorButtons();
  brushButtons();
  settingButtons();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create an array like this:

```
Button[] allButtons = new Button[100];
```

You're creating an array that **can** hold 100 `Button` instances. But that array starts out as empty. Try doing something like this:

```
println(allButtons[0]);
```

You'll see that this prints out `null`, which means that the value is basically empty. You haven't actually added any `Button` instances to your array. This is why you're getting an error: because you're trying to use values that don't exist.

To add an instance to your array, you'd do something like this:

```
allButtons[0] = new Button();
```

At which point it would be safe to do use that value:

```
allButtons[0].name = "cancel";
```

By the way, you might consider just using an `ArrayList` instead of an array. Or take advantage of Processing's array functions that allow you to add elements to an array instead of creating an array with a size of 100.

Also, in the future please try to use proper naming conventions. Variables should start with a lower-case letter, and classes should start with an upper-case letter. This makes your code much easier to read.

Comment: Thanks! Helped me out very much, and i fixed all the naming :P. I will sure check out Processing's array functions too (tbh not very informed about them) or try using an ArrayList instead ! :)